# How do I get both the date and time to displayed in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

It used to display both date and time, but after a Windows 10 update it now only displays time.

Comment: Could you explain more please? Time and Date in the taskbar? in the Kalender app? something else completely?

Comment: @NordlysJeger I think he means the default clock in the bottom right of the taskbar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: Basically, if your taskbar is too small (using small taskbar buttons), only the time will display. You have to be using the normal-size taskbar buttons in order for both the time AND date to display. Justin's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can display both date and time by doing the following:

Right-click the Taskbar and select `Taskbar Settings`. Then turn off `Use small taskbar buttons`.